# Excel VBA Out of Memory Error during Array Initialization

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I’m encountering an error in Excel 2010 (32 bit version) when trying to initialize an array. The error specifically says: “Out of Memory” I should also note that I’m coding on a 64 bit machine with 32 GB of RAM.

This is the code I am using:

```
   Sub ArrayTest()
   Dim C As Variant
   ReDim C(50257, 768) As Variant
   Dim row As Integer
   Dim column As Integer

   For row = 1 To UBound(C, 1)
       For column = 1 To UBound(C, 2)
           C(row, column) = rnd
       Next
   Next
   End Sub
```

The error occurs when I try and ReDim C().

What I tried so far:

I thought maybe I had hit the limitations of the Variant data type. So I tried to ReDim  an array of type Double. I encountered the same error. I had success using a data type of Integer, but the issue is I need to capture floating point data with this array (as the Rnd functions shows).

Somebody had recommend I try using a Byte array. However Byte arrays can only capture integer data. So that didn’t work either. Another option I considered was using the Win32 API to see if it were possible to allocate the array in memory outside of Excel. Specifically the VirtualAlloc() function. I haven’t actually tried this yet as I’m not sure it will work. I’ve been told that if the underlying program you are using is 32 bits, then it won’t work.

Anyway, at this point I am perplexed as to what I should I do. I may consider using an Access database to store the data (50257 x 768 = 38,597,376 elements of data). This will slow down the code significantly though.

Are there any ways around this?

Comment: Use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Also throw [`Randomize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement) in there too - well maybe at least give the docs a read and then decide whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Excel has a limit on memory usage at 4gb. `Variant` type [takes up 16 bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary).

So essentially you have `50257*768*16` bytes allocated just to `redim` this monster. That's `6,175,580,288` or 6.1gb.

If instead you declare that array as a `Double` you will half that size, so ~3gb or declare it as a `Single` to quarter the size at ~1.5gb and it may work out.

Comment: OP must already have a honker of a worksheet then. I added suggestion to go with single, assuming that is big enough for these millions of random numbers. It's a huge data set and a limited amount of memory so it will be a tight-rope walk to continue doing this work in excel.

Comment: Wow using Single worked like a charm. Thank you. I've never used the single data type before. What is it used for primarily? As for the honking worksheet lol, I'm trying to build a chat bot in Excel. Might make my job more interesting.

Comment: It's just a 4byte float as opposed to the 8byte Double. It will round more often then 8gb, essentially.